# How to display error message if the text box is empty on button click in WPF

Tags: wpf, textbox

I want to show an error message when the text box is empty on button click. I don't want to display error in tool tip. Show error message in a separate text block.

Comment: If I am not wrong then you must have idea to check the textBox.text!=string.IsNullOrEmpty () in Button click event. Then can you please explain the question little more?

Comment: is it possible to do this process with out code behind code?

Comment: You mean to check this in XAML only ? If yes then according to my knowledge as XAML is meant for UI purpose so its not a good idea to handle the click event and to check the TextBox empty or null case in XAML

Answer (score 0):

[This link should help you out](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfvalidation.aspx)

Implementing `IDataErrorInfo` is the most appropriate solution for error handling in WPF imho :)